# Get the current ActionBar size

Tags: android, android-actionbar, navigation-drawer

I tried several things before and searched the web, but no answer.

How do I get the current `ActionBar` size?

I styled my `ActionBar` like this:

```
<style name="MusicSlide.Theme.ActionBar" parent="android:Widget.Holo.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:height">60dp</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarSize">60dp</item>
    <item name="android:homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/ic_drawer</item>
    <item name="android:background">@color/complete_transparent</item>
    <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/MusicSlide.Theme.ActionBar.TitleText</item>
    <item name="android:subtitleTextStyle">@style/MusicSlide.Theme.ActionBar.TitleText</item>
</style>
```

It is transparent.

In my app I implemented a `DrawerLayout`. I don't want the `DrawerLayout` to be underneath the `ActionBar` , so I set the margin of the `DrawerLayout`:

```
final TypedArray styledAttributes = mContext.getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(
                new int[] { android.R.attr.actionBarSize });
        int actionheight = (int) styledAttributes.getDimension(0, 0);

        styledAttributes.recycle();
        ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams mlp = (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) mDrawerListRight
                .getLayoutParams();
        mlp.setMargins(0,(actionheight + statbarheight),0,0);
```

The problem is that `android.R.attr.actionBarSize` returns the original height of the `ActionBar`.

How do I get the `60dp` I set in my style?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`android:actionBarSize` isn't an attribute of `Widget.ActionBar`, this is why you aren't returning the correct value. Add that line to your app's theme, wherever you define `android:actionBarStyle`.